# Is the function $f: \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(r)=\frac{p}{10^q}$ one-one and onto?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Is the function $f: \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(0)=0, ~$$f(r)=\frac{p}{10^q}$ where $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in \mathbb{N}$, $(p,q)=1$, one-one and onto?

Since, for $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists no $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $f(r)=\sqrt{2}$. There fore the function is not onto.

For one-one, let $m,n\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $m\not=n$ and $m=p_1/q$, $n=p_2/q$ s.t. $(p_1,q)=1,$ $(p_2,q)=1$ and $p_1\not=p_2$.

Then $\frac{p_1}{10^q}\not=\frac{p_2}{10^q}\implies f(m)\not= f(n)\implies f$ is one-one.

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: You say $\sqrt 2\in \mathbb R $ and claim that means there is no value that goes to $\sqrt 2$. That is not valid.  After all $\frac 3{100}\in \mathbb R$ but $f (\frac 32)=\frac 3 {100} $.  I think you meant to say $\sqrt 2$ is irrational so there is no $f (r) $ equal to it.  But you don't say why not.  Why can't $f (r) $ equal an irational number?

Comment: You should note even for rational numbers like $\frac 73$ there is no $r $ so that $f (r)=\frac 73$ either.

Comment: @fleablood since the expression for $f(r)$ is rational so it can't produce an irrational number. Right? or did i miss anything?

Comment: But you never stated that $\sqrt 2$ was irrational and you never stated that $f(r)$ must be rational.  You must state those if you you use those.  And if you know that $f(r)$ is always rational then you *know* it isn't onto and you don't have to use $f(r) \ne \sqrt 2$ as an example.  It's enough to so $f(r)$ is never equal to any irrational number.  But you *do* have to prove such a statement.

Comment: @fleablood yup that's a mistake. I took it to be obvious. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could mention that $f(r)$ is always rational, while $\sqrt 2$ is not, to complete the logic for why it is not onto.

Your proof for $f$ being one-to-one is incorrect because you assume the same "q". Rather you would have $m = \dfrac{p}{q}$ and $n = \dfrac{r}{s}$.

It is often easier to start with the assumption that $f(m) = f(n)$, because if you can show then that $m = n$, this implies one-to-one by contraposition, and if you can't, it might lead you to an example showing it is not one-to-one.  In this case $f(m)=f(n)$ implies $10^s p = 10^q r$.  Trying small examples, if $q=3$, $s = r = 1$, then $p = 100$, and sure enough $m = \dfrac{100}{3}$ and $n = 1$ provides an example. ($q = 3$ was chosen because $q=2$ wouldn't have allowed $(p,q)=1$.)